# trying to read xml from a specified url yields no xml results

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

This specific [url](http://bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml) <-- (click to view) is working fine.

```
http://bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml
```

But when trying to read from it to extract currency, this is what I get no matter which way I try to tackle it ...

```
<html><body><script>document.cookie='iiiiiii=e0076bcciiiiiii_e0076bcc; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html>
```

Tried following :

```
    using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
    {
        var result = c.DownloadString(@"http://bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml");
    }
```

Tried with above `WebClient` ... but not as first try.

This next code was my first try.  What am I doing wrong ?

While "surfing" to the URL above, the XML is there.  I would like to try with your help first before desperately I could think of another way.

I would be able to save the file to my hard drive (programmatically), then read it from the hdd. For that approach I didn't test yet, though I am sure it will work.

But I was trying to check with some experienced developers to have a try on this.  What could be wrong?

```
   string DollarURL = "http://bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml";
   xx.Load(DollarURL);
   XmlNode root = xx;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be using Linq to XML for this.  Try `XDocument.Load`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(DollarURL);
```

Now `xdoc.Root` will give you the `CURRENCIES` element:

```
Console.WriteLine(xdoc.Root.Name.LocalName); // "CURRENCIES"
```

Use `xdoc.Root.Elements("CURRENCY")` to get all the currency nodes.  Use `xdoc.Save("filename")` to save to hard drive.

To query a certain currency, write it like this:

```
XElement[] usdElements = xdoc.Root.Elements("CURRENCY")
    .Where(currency => (string)currency.Element("CURRENCYCODE") == "USD")
    .ToArray();
```

---

For more info, read up on [LINQ to XML on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: cheers i was lost (: how can i search for the us Dollar lambada style on this xml ?

Comment: @LoneXcoder no prob - see my edit above for querying elements in USD.

Comment: it's not working again . this is i think to let you visit , see currency and please come back tommorow , if you will be visiting us again or try to work with this xml as datasource, have a coockie !

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to access XML nodes with XPath:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;

// ...    

using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
{
    string result = c.DownloadString(@"http://bankisrael.gov.il/currency.xml");
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(result);

    foreach (XmlNode currency in xml.SelectNodes("/CURRENCIES/CURRENCY"))
    {
        string name = currency.SelectSingleNode("NAME").InnerText;
        int unit = int.Parse(currency.SelectSingleNode("UNIT").InnerText);
        string currencyCode = currency.SelectSingleNode("CURRENCYCODE").InnerText;
        string country = currency.SelectSingleNode("COUNTRY").InnerText;
        double rate = double.Parse(currency.SelectSingleNode("RATE").InnerText, culture);
        double change = double.Parse(currency.SelectSingleNode("CHANGE").InnerText, culture);

        Console.WriteLine("{2} {0} ({3}, {5}) rate:{1} change:{4}", currencyCode, rate, unit, country, change, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: first i want to thank you for the effort you have taken to try chek on that issue even though there's an accepted answer , folowing my last comment  , thanks i will try your code , i do know there should be a work aroud i thank you for the consist atetude , i will inform you if you managed to help overcoming a safty trick of a well planed website.

Comment: no success (: i can try access another site that's does not care to be visited as a data source, my code was working for a while, i guess they were woried as looks like a kind of an attack, so two options,another site, or programatically way to download a file, no matter which tech' availble in dot net, console webforms winforms i guess it is possible if you just do it as human, download data store relevant value in sql DB then use DB so i just need to know how to download a websites page contents as if it was manually done, did we just use web client so that is closest to manually download ?